# java config объектов

Tags: java

У меня есть класс простого объекта, например man, с двумя полями name и age.
И мне нужно, чтоб при старте программы, считывался текстовый конфигурационный файл, в котором будут описаны экземпляры класса.
Например

```
[vova]
age=12

[max]
age=10
```

и т.д.
ну и дальше, я бы создал соответствующие экземпляры с этими параметрами.

Понятно, что я могу написать кастомный парсер файла...но может уже есть готовый инструмент типа properties ?

формат файла с настройками не принципиален, я привел пример на вскидку...

Comment: не уверен, что кто то заморочился и написал сериализацию для properties. Тем более у вас формат какой то странный

Answer (score 1):

Судя по всему вы хотите сериализовывать и десериализовывать Java Beans. Есть стандартная реализация этого через XML файлы.

Предположим, что ваш Java Bean представляет из себя следующий класс:

```
package com.example;

public class Human {

    private String name;
    private int age;

    public Human() {
        // needs for serialization
    }

    public Human(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Human{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", age=" + age +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Переопределение `toString()` тут необязательно. Я его сделал лишь для того, чтобы иметь возможность распечатывать объекты в демонстрационном коде. А вот и сам демонстрационный код, показывающий процесс сериализации и десериализации экземпляров класса `Human`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Human bob = new Human("Bob", 34);
    Human mary = new Human("Mary", 27);

    try (XMLEncoder encoder = new XMLEncoder(new FileOutputStream("humans.xml"))) {
        encoder.writeObject(bob);
        encoder.writeObject(mary);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try (XMLDecoder decoder = new XMLDecoder(new FileInputStream("humans.xml"))) {
        Human human1 = (Human) decoder.readObject();
        Human human2 = (Human) decoder.readObject();

        System.out.println(human1);
        System.out.println(human2);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Программа распечатает:

```
Human{name='Bob', age=34}
Human{name='Mary', age=27}
```

Тоесть в переменных `human1` и `human2` будут находиться объекты, эквивалентные тем, что находятся в переменных `bob` и `mary` соответственно.

Для рабочего кода желательно так же переопределить `equals()` и `hashCode()` в классе `Human`.

Содержимое файла `humans.xml`, в моём случае, получилось таким:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<java version="10.0.2" class="java.beans.XMLDecoder">
 <object class="com.example.Human">
  <void property="age">
   <int>34</int>
  </void>
  <void property="name">
   <string>Bob</string>
  </void>
 </object>
 <object class="com.example.Human">
  <void property="age">
   <int>27</int>
  </void>
  <void property="name">
   <string>Mary</string>
  </void>
 </object>
</java>
```